# Returning references of objects in generic functions (with pointer or non-pointer attributes)

Tags: c++, pointers, generics, constants

--University homework--

I've already worked with generic functions that look like this:

```
template<class T1, class T2, int max>
class Collection{
    T1* _elements1[max];
    T2* _elements2[max];
    int _count;
public:
    // ctor

    bool AddElement(const T1& e1, const T2& e2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            if (_elements1[i] == e1 && _elements2[i] == e2)
                return false;

        _elements1[_count] = e1;
        _elements2[_count] = e2;

        _count++;

        return true;
    }

    int GetMax()const { return max;}
    T1& GetElement1(int index)const { return *_elements1[index]; }
    T2& GetElement2(int index)const { return *_elements2[index]; }
}
```

In `main()`:

```
Collection<int, double, 6> collection;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    collection.AddElement(i, i + 0.4);

cout << collection << endl;
```

I also use `const` in `operator<<` for this class and everything works great, no compiler complaints related to `const`.

But, today I tried slightly different version of this class, which we are supposed to practice because it will be on the exam in some form.

```
template<class T1, class T2, int max>
class Collection{
    T1 _elements1[max];
    T2 _elements2[max];
    int _count;
public:
    // ctor

    int GetMax()const { return max;}
    T1& GetElement1(int index)const { return _elements1[index]; }
    T2& GetElement2(int index)const { return _elements2[index]; }
}
```

The difference here is that `T1` and `T2` aren't arrays of `pointers` but arrays of plain objects, and also in the bottom, when `return`ing, there's no need to dereference.

However, in the latter example, I'm getting this error:

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &'
```

Although I did google it and found out if I put another `const` in front of these functions like this:

```
const T1& GetElement1(int index)const { return _elements1[index]; }
const T2& GetElement2(int index)const { return _elements2[index]; }
```

the error is gone.

Granted, that solved my problem but I would rather learn why is this happening and what exactly is happening under the hood. If there's an easy way to explain the difference between the two examples I provided, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are `T1` and `T2` in the example that fails to compile?

Comment: At this stage, I'm testing with `int` and `double` respectively, with a simple for loop, calling the collection function AddElement(const T1& e1, const T2& e2). Please note that the same test is applied in the other example (where T1 and T2 are array of pointers) and it doesn't fail.

Comment: So you call both `GetElement1` and `GetElement2` but only get an error with `GetElement1`?

Comment: @NathanOliver No, I'm referring only to `T1` for the sake of brevity. I just applied `const` at the beginning of `GetElement1()` function to see if it would compile, and no - it failed in the line where `GetElement2()` was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first `Collection` version, `_elements1[index]` is of type `int *const&`. This `const` is because you access `_elements1` in `const` method (actually `this` is `const` in such case), it also means that you are not allowed to modify `_elements1[index]`. When you dereference `_elements1[index]` you will get `int&`, this is the thing `_elements1[index]` points to. So you may return it from GetElement1 which returns `T1&`.

Now to your second Collection class. Here `_elements1[index]` inside of `GetElement1` method is of type `const int&`, as before const is added because you access _elements1 inside const method. Now the reason for your error is because you cannot implicitly convert `const int&`to `int&`.

If you want to learn what type has `_elements1[index]` in various places you can use below trick:

```
template<typename T>
struct TD;

// ...

T1& GetElement1(int index)const { 
    TD<decltype(_elements1[index])> tt;        
    return _elements1[index]; 
    }
```

will output error with exact type of what is inside above decltype :

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<const int &>'
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ - type of _elements1[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
T1& GetElement1(int index)const { return _elements1[index]; }
```

For member function, compiler will pass the class itself (this) to the function as the first parameter. Due to the const qualifier after member function declaration , the first parameter of GetElement1 is const Collection rather than Collection

**Edit:**

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

template<class T1, class T2, int max>
class Collection{
    T1* _elements1[max];
    T2* _elements2[max];
    int _count;
public:
    Collection() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
            _elements1[i] = new T1{};
            _elements2[i] = new T2{};
        }
    }
    int GetMax()const { return max;}
    const T1& GetElement1(int index) const {
        // _elements1[0] = new T1{}; Error, the pointer is constant
        _elements1[0]->resize(5); // Ok, the pointed object isn't constant
        return *_elements1[index];
    }
    const T2& GetElement2(int index) const { return *_elements2[index]; }
};

int main() {
    Collection<std::string, std::string, 5> c;
    const std::string& rs = c.GetElement1(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, and why the same error isn't showing when `T1` is an array of pointers  and I return it (dereferenced)?

Comment: @developer10 - The pointers are pointing to things outside the class. The pointers might be constant, but not the things they point to.

Comment: @BoPersson So even though I'm returning the value itself (example with pointers, note the "*"): `T1& GetElement1(int index)const { return *_elements1[index]; }`, it makes a difference in this scenario?

Comment: @developer10 In this case, _elements1 is an array of pointers, the array itself and all the elements of the array (that's pointers) are constant, which means you can't modify the pointers to point to other object, but you can modify the object the pointer points to.

Comment: I think I understand. That may indeed be the case here. I will have to learn more about how `const` works. Thanks everyone!